# Created contour lines do not show up in rendered image

Tags: rendering

I'm not really familiar with blender yet, though trying to create a render of a imported DEM through the GIS addon gave me some nice results now trying to create a fly-through my created contour lines do not show up in the final render/animations. After checking most settings I can not find out why this would happen. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screen shot of viewport and render]

Comment: How did you create the contour lines?

Comment: maybe you should convert the lines into curves (select the object in object mode RMB convert to curves). Then in the object properties panel for the curve you can add a bevel under the bevel menu you change the depth.

Comment: I managed to fix it, @gladys thanks for the info. I had tried this already before but the objects data panel would not should after searching in the search bar I managed to change the bevel and I am able to render it!